# How to use a custom created POSIXlt Date class in colClasses argument when importing with fread in R?

Tags: r, date, import, data.table, posixlt

I am trying to import date fields which are formatted as a character, into a `POSIXlt` class while importing the data itself. Instead of importing the date as character and converting to `POSIXlt` later, I want to do this in one step, since my data is quite big (4+ GB). Below is the code for the same.

In this code, I define a new 'myDate' class and using it to pass into the `colClasses` argument. This method works with `read.delim`, but not on `fread` from `data.table` pkg.

It would be great if this is made to work with `fread` because, I will save at least 20 Min of time with `fread` method, if this works. Can you make it to work with `fread` or suggest a better alternative ?

```
library (data.table)
library (lubridate)
setClass ('myDate')

# create custom 'myDate' class. Having "Date" or "POSIXlt" in colClasses argument of read.table does not work
setAs ("character","myDate", function(from) as.POSIXlt(fast_strptime(from, "%Y-%m-%d")) )   

ccs <- c ("logical", "myDate", "myDate", "character") 

# fread() Does NOT Work 
rawdata <- fread ("filepath/filename.txt", colClasses=css, sep='|', header=FALSE,)) 

# WORKS!
rawdata <- read.delim ("filepath/filename.txt", colClasses=ccs, sep='|', header=FALSE)
```

Comment: word of caution, regardless of how you read the data, `data.table` will not play with `POSIXlt`

Comment: Can you explain more, when you say `data.table` will not play with `POSIXlt` ?

Comment: `POSIXlt` is a needlessly large data type (it uses 40 bytes iirc) and `data.table` will not store it as a simple column. You should use `POSIXct` instead if you want to store it in a `data.table`.